# Azure Pipelines - How to make agent in Agent Pool to be online?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

How to make agent in Agent Pool to be online?

[image: Agent Pool Status]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start the agent service on the agent. If its started, verify it can connect to the Azure Devops. Check agent logs to see why it fails to connect.